# Create dynamic authorization policies in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: authorization, asp.net-identity, blazor, webassembly

We have a Blazor Webassembly Hosted application. Authentication against our own IdSrv4 application, which works fine. Basic Authorization based on Roles and or Policies are not a problem to achieve, but this is sufficient for us.
Each user will, based on their roles, have access to one or more "functions". A function defines access to a specific part of the application (might be as fine grained as field level or larger scenarios like a work flow).

The examples that I find are of the simple kind, like how to create a "Over21Policy" and so on. This is not doable for us since we have hundreds of these functions.

I think that there MUST be a way to send parameters to the policy requirement and make it "dynamic"!? So given the age policies that often make up examples, there must be a way to have the policy be used like "OverGivenAgePolicy(30)".

I have implemented an AuthorizationHandler

```
MyAuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessFunctionRequirement>
```

overriding the

```
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                           AccessFunctionRequirement requirement)
            {              
                // Get functions for user
                var functions = GetFunctionsForUser(userId);
    
// Check if the user has the required access function
                if (functions.Any(f => f == requirement.AccessFunction))
                    context.Succeed(requirement);               
            }
        }
```

where the function requirement is implemented like

```
public class AccessFunctionRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public AuthFunctions.AccessFunctions AccessFunction { get; }

        public AccessFunctionRequirement(AuthFunctions.AccessFunctions accessFunc)
        {
            AccessFunction = accessFunc;
        }
    }
```

BUT, now the problems arise.
When building and adding the policy to the pipeline I would have to specify an actual AccessFunction:

```
 public static AuthorizationPolicy HasAccessPolicy()
        {
            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddRequirements(new AccessFunctionRequirement(SOME_STATIC_ACCESSFUNCTION))
                                                   .Build();
        }
```

Obviously this hasn´t solved anything as it would still require as many policies as we have access functions.
The other problem is, even if I could define the policy to be "dynamic", when using the policy in say a component, how would I make it possible to add the access function(s) needed for this specific component/field etc?

```
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "HasAccessPolicy(NEEDS_TO_GIVE_FUNCTIONS_HERE)")]
```

This kind of authorization must be well known since the examples from MS truly are only functional for "Hello World" kind of solutions. So, is there a way to perhaps inherit the Authorize attribute and make it work, though then I would still need to solve the registration of the Policy during DI initiation.

The other possibility, very probable, is that I have missed something very basic in all of this that would make implementation of such a scenario easy?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @BrianParker, yes actually I found that article yesterday after posting this. Will try to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

See link in Brians comment, that hopefully makes up a decent implementation strategy.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.